# Conflicting "back to top" scripts - how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using 2 scripts found on the internet, one for a smooth scroll to a DIV at the bottom of the page, and one for a smooth scroll "Back to top". The issue is that there's a conflict between both and therefore the "back to top" one doesn't work (no back to top on click). Used independently they both work perfectly.

How could I "merge" them both into one single script? (and keep the fade-in fade-out effect of the back to top script) See http://jsfiddle.net/GjsVq/1/

Many thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = 220;
    var duration = 500;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
        } else {
            jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
        }
    });

    jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
        return false;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally just use one smooth scroll function and then set my "go to top" button with a href="#idOfHighestElementOnPage".  This is the smooth scroll function (which may include something helpful if you don't want to go the same route I went):

```
$(function () {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
            }, 'normal');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
})

window.onscroll = scrollFunction;
function scrollFunction() {
    var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
    var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);
    if (top > 200) {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but in that case I loose the fade-in fade-out effect of the back to top button unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

`$('a[href^="#"]').on(...` is selecting both `<a>` elements. One approach is to either rewrite this selector to match only the `<a>` elements that should force a scroll to the bottom (maybe use a CSS class for this?)

An alternative, quick-and-dirty fix would be to reset the event handlers on the "back-to-top" element before attaching its own click handler: `jQuery('.back-to-top').off().click(...`